# Question on Google Provisioning API and SSO Password change propagation

Tags: api, google-app-engine, passwords, single-sign-on, provisioning

I'm using the Google Apps Provisioning API to synchronize user data with our internal database (MySQL). For every new user created through our site's backend, a corresponding user in created in the GoogApp system. Change is passwords are also synchronized accordingly.

I'm about to implement SSO, so that logins performed on our website automatically makes the user login into the google apps too.

My question is what happens IF the user happens to change his/her password using the **Account > Settings** in the googapps interface, instead of our own backend? Our system has no way of knowing about the change! Is there a way in Prov API or SSO with which I can **turn off** the password changing mechanism in googapp engine and let the user do it ONLY through our backend?

Anyone who's used / setup a similar system, please shed some light on it.

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have SSO enabled in your Google Apps domain you have to provide a "change password" URL, that way when the users tries to go "Setting"->"Change Password" they will be redirected to your custom URL and make the password change in your backend.

Comment: I discovered the same a couple of days back while fiddling with the GA control panel. What I couldn't figure out is, in all the docs, it says that this enables the password changing for GA WebApps. But does that include the mail service too? Coz that is my primary concern. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: You are right, it's only for webapps. For IMAP/POP/API access then you'll need to provide the password stored in Google Apps. You can include, in your change password application, the logic for synchronizing the password with Google Apps through the Provisioning API.